# using Regex to iterate over a string and search for 3 consecutive hyphens and replace it with [space][hyphen][space]

Tags: c#, regex

I currently have a string which looks like this when it is returned :

```
//This is the url string
// the-great-debate---toilet-paper-over-or-under-the-roll

string name = string.Format("{0}",url);
name = Regex.Replace(name, "-", " ");
```

And when I perform the following Regex operation it becomes like this :

```
 the great debate  toilet paper over or under the roll
```

However, like I mentioned in the question, I want to be able to apply regex to the url string so that I have the following output:-

```
 the great debate - toilet paper over or under the roll
```

I would really appreciate any assistance.

[EDIT] However, not all the strings look like this, some of them just have a single hyphen so the above method work

```
 world-water-day-2016
```

and it changes to

```
 world water day 2016
```

but for this one:

```
the-great-debate---toilet-paper-over-or-under-the-roll
```

I need a way to check if the string has 3 hyphens than replace those 3 hyphens with [space][hyphen][space]. And than replace all the remaining single hyphens between the words with space.

Comment: [Without regex](https://ideone.com/05sUsy): `url.Replace("---", "[ \uFFFD ]").Replace("-", " ").Replace("[ \uFFFD ]", " - ")`

Comment: Ah, missed that you wanted the hyphens between words as well.

Comment: Do you have to handle 2 hyphens or more than 3 that are together?

Comment: A regex one: `Regex.Replace(s, @"-(-)-|-", m => m.Groups[1].Success ? " - " : " ")`.

Comment: Ok, so a url returns a string like this: `world-water-day-2016` or `the-great-debate---toilet-paper-over-or-under`

Comment: The one with which has 3 hyphens will need to be replaced with a single hyphen, and all other single hyphens between words must be replaced by a space. I hope I am more clear.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew let me try the regex one out !

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew works like a charm, can you explain to me how you arrived to this solutions, just so that I understand for the future. Thanks

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it strips the last 2 words out

Comment: @UmarAftab It doesn't. BTW, see CAustin's solution, might work for you, too.

Comment: CAustin's solutions did not remove the hyphens

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you are right it doesn't , I was actually trimming it before sending it forward.. Sorry about that ! Your solution works awesome. Can you kindly explain it or send me a link where I can learn about it. I would appreciate that.

Comment: Wait, does it mean your strings do not always have letter/digits on both sides of the hyphens? OK, I will post the solution.

Comment: @UmarAftab I'm not sure why my solution wouldn't work for you. Maybe you need to double escape the word border characters like `\\b`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there is always a very naive solution to this kind of problem: you replace your specific matches in context with some chars that are not usually used in the current environment and after replacing generic substrings you may replace the temporary substrings with the necessary exception.

```
var name = url.Replace("---", "[ \uFFFD ]").Replace("-", " ").Replace("[ \uFFFD ]", " - ");
```

You may also use a regex based replacement that matches either a 3-hyphen substring capturing it, or just match a single hyphen, and then check if Group 1 matched inside a match evaluator (the third parameter to `Regex.Replace` can be a Match evaluator method).

It will look like

```
var name = Regex.Replace(url, @"(---)|-", m => m.Groups[1].Success ? " - " : " ");
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/cCwLgt).

So, when `(---)` part matches, the 3 hyphens are put into Group 1 and the `.Success` property is set to `true`. Thus, `m => m.Groups[1].Success ? " - " : " "` replaces 3 hyphens with space+`-`+space and 1 hyphen (that may be actually 1 of the 2 consecutive hyphens) with a space.

Comment: Great explanation ! Awesome ! Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using LINQ rather than Regex:

```
var str = "the-great-debate---toilet-paper-over-or-under-the-roll";
var result = str.Split(new string[] {"---"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
                .Select(s => s.Replace("-", " "))
                .Aggregate((c,n) => $"{c} - {n}");

// result = "the great debate - toilet paper over or under the roll"
```

Split the string up based on the `---`, then remove hyphens from each substring, then join them back together.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way:

```
name = Regex.Replace(name, "\b-|-\b", " ");
```

The show-off way:

```
name = Regex.Replace(name, "(\b)?-(?(1)|\b)", " ");
```

Comment: I tried it, but it somehow was not removing the hyphens at all.

Comment: Try double escaping? It definitely works on the example you provided. See https://regex101.com/r/aStQ7L/2

Comment: ` \ ` is a C# escape character, so `\b` represents the backspace character. You should start your strings with `@"` if you don't want to use C# escape sequences, or use `\\` instead of `\`

Comment: @JacobKrall Thanks for shedding light onto why it would not work.

Comment: @CAustin thanks for enlightening me with a different way of doing it.